# how to implement not-required DateField using Flask-WTF

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want a DateField which is optional,
but I got a "Not a valid date value" error if leave it empty

I add some logs in the source code of wtforms, and found
formdata.getlist(self.name) returns [u''] for this DateField

The code of my form:

```
from wtforms import BooleanField, TextField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators, HiddenField, DateField, SelectField
from flask_wtf import Form

class EmployeeForm(Form):
    id = HiddenField('id')
    title = TextField('Title')
    start = DateField('Start Date', format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite and old topic, but someone might still run into the same problem, so I'll put my possible answer for that.
Adding `validators.Optional()` does not help here, because the field is marked as error earlier during the processing stage.
You can patch the processor's behaviour like this:

```
class NullableDateField(DateField):
    """Native WTForms DateField throws error for empty dates.
    Let's fix this so that we could have DateField nullable."""
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            date_str = ' '.join(valuelist).strip()
            if date_str == '':
                self.data = None
                return
            try:
                self.data = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, self.format).date()
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid date value'))
```

Comment: I cannot verify that there would be any problems just using `validators.Optional()`.

Comment: Finally! Thank you for this. I can confirm Optional did not work for me, still returned not a valid date value. This works flawlessly.

Answer (score 53):

You are looking for the [`Optional`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html#built-in-validators) validator.

```
start = DateField('Start Date', format='%m/%d/%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
```